# Creating dynamic one-time Javascript event listeners for Audio player timestamps

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I want to produce a series of unique messages based on timestamps while an audio file is playing via an  HTML5 element. My approach to doing this is to loop through an object array comprised of key value pairs where the key is message and the value is the timestamp (in seconds), and create an event listener bound to the audio player's timeupdate event. When the event fires, it checks if the current timestamp of the audio player is greater than the value of the bound key, and removes itself to avoid firing again:

```
function addAudio() {
  audio = document.createElement('audio');
  audio.id = "test";
  audio.src = "https://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3";
  document.querySelector('body').prepend(audio);
}

function playAudio() {
  document.getElementById('test').play();
}

function setupListeners() {
  var items = {
    'message1': 1.5,
    'message2': 3.5,
    'message3': 4.5
  }

  for (var key in items) {
    console.log(key + " to start at " + (items[key]));

    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {

      if (this.currentTime > items[key]) {

        console.log(key[value])

        document.getElementById('test').removeEventListener('timeupdate', arguments.callee);
      }
    });
  }
}

addAudio();
playAudio();
setupListeners();
```

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to accomplish is fundamentally wrong because of the Audio player or because of my understanding of dynamic event listener generation. I can confirm the event listeners are being created, but the conditional that checks to see if the currentTime of the audio player is greater than any of the listener's value never seems to resolve to true.

If there is a better approach to take (again, the requirement is to execute code based on a predetermined set of timestamps (with minor variance allowed given the rate of the timeupdate event firing), please let me know.

Comment: Whatever 1.5 is (1.5sec? 1.5 days?...?) Wouldn't the first timestamp have to be the time in which the audio player will surpass first since time is linear? Wouldn't the rest of that object be pointless?

Comment: The audio player API returns time in floating points integers so it the numbers in my array were to match that same type. The concept is that the events would be bound and that the audio player would routinely emits its current time for the event listeners to recompare themselves to.

Comment: Iterating through an array is quick, you either have to slow down looping with `.setTimeout()` on every iteration or just react to each time `timeupdate` event fires then compare `.currenTime` vs. value -- then move on to the next value in array by incrementing a number by closure. Never add/remove the same listeners multiple times on the same element. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000462/2813224)

Answer (score 2):

### Problems

1. The `for...in` loop is problematic. It's adding identical event listeners on the same `<audio>`. If there were three identical event listeners bound to the `<audio>` it would trigger 3 times every @250ms. Once every @250ms is clearly enough.
2. If we intend to remove an event listener we must:

   1. Create an `.addEventListener()` that invokes a named function. See **Figure I**.
   2. Create a `.removeEventListener()` with a signature identical to the `.addEventListener()` it's intended to remove. See **Figure II**.

      **Figure I** - Using a named function as the event handler

      ```js
      // DOM Object / a reference to an element
      const btn = document.querySelector("button");
      btn.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

      // Details about event handlers proceeds Figure II
      function handleClick(event) {
        const clk = event.target;
        console.log(clk.timeStamp);
      }
      ```

      **Figure II** - `.add/removeEventListener()` signatures

      ```js
      /*
      ¹The element bound to registered event, ²the event, and 
      the ³event handler must be identical.
      */
      btn.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
      /*↖️                   ⬆️         ⬆️
           DOM Object¹      event²  event handler³
        ↙️                   ⬇️         ⬇️    */
      btn.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
      ```

      An event handler is simply a function that is called when a registered event is triggered. When the event handler is a named function:

      1. As the second parameter of an `.add/removeEventListener()` omit the parenthesis. Event handlers wait to be invoked, and if suffixed with `()`, it would be invoked once it was parsed instead.
      2. Define the named function outside of event listener.
3. `"timeupdate"` event fires @250ms or @4 times a second. If we were to use the values of the `items` array in the **OP** (**O**riginal **P**ost) code, the first value would resolve to true eventually -- then the `"timeupdate"` event would be removed, since we should have only one event listener of that kind bound to the `<audio>` (see #1), it's pointless to have anything past the first object in the `items` array.

### Solution

If your objective was to log a message at multiple predetermined times, then just add and remove the event listener once. See **Example A**. It just makes no sense to add and remove the same event listener multiple times over the same element - moreover it amounts to inefficient code bloat that provides no advantage -- an [anti-pattern](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/antipatterns-to-avoid-in-code/). See **Example B** if you want to remove an event listener at a predetermined time.

**Details are commented in both Example A and Example B**

### Example A

```js
// Reference <audio>
const A = document.querySelector('audio');

// Bind <audio> to the "timeupdate" event
A.addEventListener('timeupdate', timedMsg);

const messages = [{
    timestamp: 1.5,
    message: "@1.5sec - MSG: ",
    terminate: false
  },
  {
    timestamp: 3.75,
    message: "@3.75ec - MSG: ",
    terminate: false
  },
  {
    timestamp: 6.35,
    message: "@6.35sec - MSG: ",
    terminate: false
  },
  {
    timestamp: 7,
    message: null,
    terminate: true
  }
];

/*
When incrementing a number value, define it outside of function. 
Google "javascript closure"
*/
let i = 0;
/*
Event handler passes Event Object by default
If <audio>'s .currentTime is equal to or greater than the value of an
object's ["timestamp"] property at the current index of the messages 
array...
...log the object's ["message"] value...
...increment i...
...If the current object's ["terminate"] is true, remove event listener
*/
function timedMsg(e) {
  if (this.currentTime >= messages[i].timestamp) {
    console.log(messages[i].message);
    i++;
    if (messages[i].terminate) {
      A.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timedMsg);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font: 300 2ch/1 Consolas
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

audio {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<audio src="https://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3" controls></audio>
```

### Example B

```js
// Reference <audio> and <input>
const A = document.querySelector('audio');
const I = document.querySelector('input');

/*
Bind <audio> to the "loadedmetadata" event...
...set <input>'s .max and .value to <video>'s .duration
*/
A.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
  I.max = this.duration;
  I.value = this.duration;
 }

// Bind <audio> to the "timeupdate" event
A.addEventListener('timeupdate', cutoff);

/*
Event handler passes Event Object by default
If <audio>'s .currentTime is greater than <input>'s .value...
...unbind <audio> from the "timeupdate" event...
...log <audio>'s .currentTime everytime "timeupdate" fires (@250ms)
*/
function cutoff(e) {
  if (this.currentTime > I.value) {
    A.removeEventListener('timeupdate', cutoff);
  }
  console.log(this.currentTime);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font: 300 2ch/1 Consolas
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

audio {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2rem;  
}

input {
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 6.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<audio src="https://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3" controls></audio>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label>Set Cutoff Time 
  <input type='number' min='0' step='any'>
</label>
```